# On adding the service reference, data source files are not created

Tags: wcf

Recently I added a WCF service and wanted to use them in my MVC application.

Right clicked on Service References-> Add Service reference and added the service.

However in the Service References folder i see that the files with following extensions are added. 
.svcinfo, .disco, .wsdl, .xsd, Reference.cs and svcmap.

and the .datasource file is not added(Compared with other projects).

I also read that .datasource files is not required all the time. Then why the datasource files were automatically added in the other project? And which setting am I missing.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely not normal behavior.

Regarding whether they are "not required all the time", they are used by designer tools to offer pre-canned data source selections when creating an object data source. They are not compiled [and have no runtime effect] and hence can be safely deleted if you don't intend to use this mechanism to feed data to controls.

There is no way to control generation or not of the `.datasource` files - the main thing that dictates that is whether the WSDL defines any such structures.

If you are using a Shared Contracts DLL and have configured that in the Service Reference, they'll get added under `\Properties\DataSources`.

If you omit to specify that option, they'll get nested underneath the `.svcmap` file in Solution Explorer tree.

Answer (score -1):

The datasource are optional files that help to bind a data contract to a ui control.

Here is an example how to do it:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee373840.aspx

But I don't know if is there a way to turn off the generation of these files.

Comment: This is at best a comment (and the question is why is it *not* getting generated)

Comment: Yes, would you prefer if I didnt give a reason? For me from the OP, it's clear that the poster knows how to do it, but in some cases it doesnt work. You're telling how to do it on a sunny day and telling him you don't know anythig about how it doesnt work (I didnt intend to answer at the time I downvoted or commeted but as it happens I worked out the the basis on which it works and documented it in my answer [partially becausee I'm only 99% confiident I'm correct and would appreciate a comment and/or downvote if I turn out to be wrong.]). Do you feel this is fair or not?

Comment: By the way, I do appreciate you were only trying to help the OP (and in a far more timely fashion than me), but the best way to do that, unless you are actually solving the problem is by asking questions, either to help you answer the question correctly, or to provoke the questioner to either self-solve or improve the question

Comment: No problem, but, according to the SO says about downvote, I just don't think my answer meets any of this: "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect". Regards.

Comment: Yes, you're by no means at the top of that scale. But you also didnt answer the question. Now I've had the interaction with you and you've been reasonable I'd remove the downvote (except it would require an edit). But I still stand behind the fact that 1) it could be a comment 2) half of the answer is telling the OP things they clearly already know and 3) you didnt solve the problem. Point 3 is what puts it in comment territorry for me

Comment: I understood your points @RubenBartelink, you're right. When I answered this question I had just a couple of months in SO, I probably would post a different answer today.